# Concrete5 5.7 Block permissions

Tags: permissions, block, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

Simple question. How can I add permission to edit one single block in the whole website for one user/group? I just can't figure it out. I want to make a small website with only one area editable for client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete5 accomodates this type of use case by [enabling advanced permissions](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/using-concrete5/dashboard/system-and-maintenance/permissions-and-access/advanced-permissions/enabling-advanced-permissions/) and then setting the [edit permission on a block](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/using-concrete5/dashboard/system-and-maintenance/permissions-and-access/advanced-permissions/area-block-and-file-permissions/).

NOTE: You cannot revert back to simple permissions after enablign advanced permissions. I highly recommend doing this in a test environment first and then making sure everything else works ok for you since this can introduce added complexity with other permissions as well. Another great idea is to take a database & files backup prior to enabling advanced permissions so you can revert if necessary.